# c# Json get all parent and child values

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have a json string.

There are multiple subcategories within the json string depending on the category.
I want to combine them all.
It should always give the Id of the last child level of a higher level.

Sample :

```
Id   - Name
--     ----------
1239 - Accessory> Jewelery > wristband> Silver wristband
```

Can anyone help me . Thanks

```
    {
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 368,
      **"name": "Accessory ",**
      "parentId": null,
      "subCategories": [
        {
          "id": 396,
          **"name": "Jewelery ",**
          "parentId": 368,
          "subCategories": [
            {
              "id": 397,
              **"name": "wristband",**
              "parentId": 396,
              "subCategories": [
                {
                  "id": 1238,
                  "name": "Gold wristband",
                  "parentId": 397,
                  "subCategories": []
                },
                {
                  **"id": 1239,**
                  "name": "Silver wristband",
                  "parentId": 397,
                  "subCategories": []
                },
                {
                  "id": 2845,
                  "name": "Steel wristband",
                  "parentId": 397,
                  "subCategories": []
                },
                {
                  "id": 3171,
                  "name": "Pearl wristband",
                  "parentId": 397,
                  "subCategories": []
                },
                {
                  "id": 3883,
                  "name": "diamond wristband",
                  "parentId": 397,
                  "subCategories": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here my class

```
public class SubCategory
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int parentId { get; set; }
        public List<object> subCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object parentId { get; set; }
        public List<SubCategory> subCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? Did you have any error that you could share while you tried to convert the JSON?

Comment: I gave a sample. I want to know how can I do this.

Comment: Oh thanks to the edit of @huMpty duMpty I realised my answer wasn't what you asked i'm gonna edit it asap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can drop SubCategory,  what is that `List<object>` doing there anyway?

Assuming you can deserialize

```
public class Category
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int? parentId { get; set; }   // int?
    public List<Category> subCategories { get; set; }  // <Category>
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
}
```

then you can use a simple depth-first recursive visitor:

```
string FindCategoryTrail(List<Category> categories, int id)
{
   foreach(var category in categories)
   {
       if (category.id == id)  return category.name;

       var trail = FindCategoryTrail(category.subCategories , id);
       if (trail != null)
       {
          return category.name + " > " + trail;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

and call it like

```
string trail = FindCategoryTrail(myRoot.categories, 1239);
```

Comment: Damnit I was about edit my answer to post the (almost) same code, you were faster :(

Comment: Thank you so much Hank. This is exactly what i wanted. And the others Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

using Linq, you could flatten the nested lists:

```
public class Category
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object parentId { get; set; }
    public List<Category> subCategories { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
        IEnumerable<Category> Flatten(IEnumerable<Category> e) => e.SelectMany(c => Flatten(c.subCategories)).Concat(e);

        Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(File.ReadAllText(@"U:\test1.json"));
        var search = Flatten(root.categories).Where(c => c.id == 1239);

        foreach(var s in search)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"id: {s.id}");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"name: {s.name}");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"parentid: {s.parentId}");
        }
```